# Mariadb failure to daemonise with docker

Tags: docker, mariadb

I'm trying to use this image https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/ (any version).

I'm using the following to launch the container:

```
cd maria
docker build -t maria-image .
docker run --name maria maria-image -d -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1 
cd ..
```

I'm preparing a custom build in case I need to do any future modifications so that lives in maria/Dockerfile with the following:

```
FROM mariadb:5.5
MAINTAINER ...
EXPOSE 3306
```

If I do docker ps -a I get status "Exited (2) 5 seconds ago".

Comment: `docker logs maria`

Comment: Do what Matt said or run without -d and see the errors for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your args appear to be in the wrong order, maria-image should be after all other docker run args:

```
docker run --name maria -d -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1 maria-image
```

The version you ran passed the -d and -e as the command for docker to run. Note that you'll want to first run `docker rm -v maria` to free the container name for reuse.

Comment: that totally helped. Thanks!